# How to set up ssh for non-github servers on msysgit

Tags: git

I saw [**this**](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) tutorial on how to set up msysgit for github.

The problem is I'm trying to set it up on my webserver that's run by hostgator.

I'm trying to follow along with [**this**](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) tutorial but I can't do push to the server.

Is there somewhere on the server (hostgator's) that I can pair with the output of:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "me@mail.com"
```

EDIT:

[**This**](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/ssh-keying-through-putty-on-windows-or-linux) support page shows how to get ssh up and running in windows. I don't know what to do with that tho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't trust a host provider that's not setup for git like Heroku or AppHarbor is. This may be more trouble than it's worth and setting up a local repo with hooks to ftp the working directory to hostgator would be less of a problem to set up.

Comment: Take a look at git hooks in the progit.org/book

Comment: ooh, I see what you mean, but I want to be able to keep track of the changes on the server too. I also want to set up multiple workstations.

Comment: from [**here**](http://cuppster.com/2011/01/30/using-git-to-remotely-install-website-updates/) it looks like it can be done without ftp, and that's with hostgator